# Как в SQL Server добавить связи между таблицами?

Tags: sql-server

Помогите разобраться, работал в MySQL, там можно графически создать связи между таблицами, т.е. **Один к одному, Один ко многим, Многие ко многим**, сейчас перешел в MS SQL Server, как тут создавать данные связи? В интернете не нашел тем, которые хорошо бы объяснили данный вопрос, в основном все уходит в SQL, но неужели по другому никак?

Comment: Не надо создавать связи графически. Создавай как все нормальные люди - DDL-запросом. А потом реверснёшь и посмотришь, что и как нарисовалось в схеме.

Comment: @Akina я все время в диаграммах рисовал :D зато теперь ушел в mysql  и тут пишу ручками

Comment: на в дереве объектов а базе есть диаграммы. вот создаете новую, закидываете таблицы, и таскаете столбцы с одной на другую